# How auto package installation of Grunt, Karma, package.json in one process

Tags: gruntjs, karma-runner, package.json

This is more of a question without code so, please forgive me.

Is there a way programatically create a Package.json, karma.conf.js and gruntfile.js without building them individually.

I want to automate the process without having to build each one individually.

Also, the same for creating a Spec.js file for describe testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into Yeoman generators to see if any of the pre-existing ones are in line with what you are aiming to create. It's a fairly straight forward node tool that scaffolds out an app skeleton for you.

http://yeoman.io/generators/

If not, there's a fair bit of information available on how to write your own generator here: 
http://yeoman.io/authoring/

Comment: Thank you kind fellow programmer. This is a start and it's what I was seeking